# filepicker example code for rails to get S3 url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, filepicker.io

Can someone show me an example of how to get the amazon S3 url after my Rails form uploads a file? My application has the filepicker.io/etc/etc url when I use the  but I want the actual amazon url.

https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails#accessing-filepicker-file-with-onchange

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't have a complete answer, but I've been trying to figure out this same thing for the past couple of days. Here's my form field:

```
<div class="filepicker">
    <%= f.label :filepicker_url, "Upload an image:" %>
    <%= f.filepicker_field :filepicker_url, dragdrop: true, mimetypes: 'image/*', onchange: 'onImageUpload()', button_class: "btn btn-gray", id: "filepicker" %>
</div>
```

This is the js that goes with it:

```
var base_url = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/YOUR_S3_BUCKET/"

function onImageUpload() {
    filepicker.pickAndStore(

      {mimetype:"image/*"},

      {location:"S3", access: "public"}, 

      function(InkBlobs){
        var key = (JSON.stringify(InkBlobs[0].key));
        key = key.replace("\"","");
        var url = base_url + key;
        $('#filepicker').val(url);
        console.log($('#filepicker').val());
      }, 

      function(FPError){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(FPError));
      });
}
```

This is for storing your files/images in your own s3 bucket and using that url directly (less dependence on ink). The S3 url is your base url plus the s3 key returned in the InkBlob. I am trying to insert the url into my input field using jquery... but for some unknown reason, it does not save with my user. I can see that it is being entered in my input field with console.log, but don't know why it isn't being saved.

I am also having issues with mismatched protocols (http vs https) with iframe. And although I haven't been able to store a filepicker_url yet, I keep reading about issues with turbolinks.

Anyways, hope this helped some. Let me know if you figure out any more.